# Why is there a math domain error when using sine?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm not sure why, but every time I try and run this, I get a math domain on error on this function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def lawofsinsang(A,B,a,b):
    if not A and B:
        if a and b:
            return (math.asin((((math.sin(B)) * a) / b)))
    else:
        return A

for i in range(0,6):
    angA = lawofsinsang(angA,angB,sideA,sideB)
    angA = lawofsinsang(angA,angC,sideA,sideC)
    angB = lawofsinsang(angB,angA,sideB,sideA)
    angB = lawofsinsang(angB,angC,sideB,sideC)
    angC = lawofsinsang(angC,angA,sideC,sideA)
    angC = lawofsinsang(angC,angB,sideC,sideB)
```

Ok so I updated the code, and instead of a domain error, `math.asin` just does nothing. New return is below:

```
math.asin(((math.sin(B)) * a) / b)
```

Comment: Probably not your problem, but are you sure you mean `if not A and B`, not `if not A and not B`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should probably have added more context. I want to check to make sure that there is no angle A but that there is an angle B as well as a side a and a side b. I want to use the law of sines to find the measure for angle A.

Comment: OK, sorry. Thats just a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you pass to `asin` (inverse sine) must be in the interval [-1, 1]. If it's not you get a domain error.

Comment: Ok so I broke down the math and I found that I was getting a number that was about -.657, but when i added the `math.asin`, it didn't change the number.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The sin function expected the parameter to already be in radians, while I had been using degrees. New code is below:

```
def lawofsinsang(A,B,a,b):
    if not A and B:
        if a and b:
            return math.degrees(math.asin(((math.sin(math.radians(B))) * a) / b))
    else:
        return A
```